# What is this name of the shot used in Carrie (1976)?

Tags: cinematography

I saw this shot in so many movies: Cape Fear (1991) also.

So what is the name of this shot used?

[image]

Comment: Related (if not even duplicate): [Camera shot with close-up next to farther away standing person](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/10292/49)